# Count the number of conditions satisfied by a set of variable values

Tags: scala

Is there any way to check how many condition each variable can satisfy?

For ex.

```
var x=1;

var y=2;
```

And I have three conditions

```
x>=y, x!=y, x<=y
```

Here two condition satisfied by these values.

So how can I do this without nested if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return the number of satisfied condition to the specified `x` and `y` values.

```
def countTrue (x:Int, y:Int):Int = 
  List(x>=y, x!=y, x<=y).filter(_==true).length
```

or as @ChrisMartin mentioned in the comment, using `count(identity)` is much simpler.

```
def countTrue (x:Int, y:Int):Int =
  List(x>=y, x!=y, x<=y).count(identity)
```

The console output:

```
scala> countTrue(1,2)
res0: Int = 2
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `.count(identity)` instead of `.filter(_==true).length`

Comment: @ChrisMartin Yes, it is much more simpler. I updated the answer.